# sIFR 3 r436: how to get really big fonts

Tags: sifr, font-size

For some reason I can't seem to get sIFR to display fontsize larger than about 126 px. I've tried to change the MAX_FONT_SIZE found in sifr.js, but it's no use.

I've also tried adjusting different fontsizes in the css, but it won't go higher than 126px.

Does anybody know how to get sIFR to display a really large fontsize?

-- Ploma --

Answer (score 0):

I believe I put in that max because Flash itself didn't let me go higher.

Answer (score 0):

`MAX_FONT_SIZE` is also in the Actionscript. It must be a limitation of Flash. I have tried increasing it without any luck.